# Should I start internal methods with _?

Tags: python, python-3.x, naming-conventions

If I have an object that has several internal functions that are not exactly meant for outside calls. Should I always start them with `_` or `__`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is indicated by [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that you should use *a single underscore* to indicate that these should be of internal use:

> In addition, the following special forms using leading or trailing underscores are recognized (these can generally be combined with any case convention):
>
> - `_single_leading_underscore` : weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. `from M import *` does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.

Double leading underscores can also be used but, those are subject to name mangling:

> - `__double_leading_underscore` : when naming a class attribute, invokes name mangling (inside `class FooBar`, `__boo` becomes `_FooBar__boo`).

so be aware of that fact.